# Google+ unable to insert moment

Tags: oauth, google-plus

Trying [example](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert#examples) from g+ documentation with `Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0: ON`. Got `Unauthorized` as result. Here's output:

```
Request

POST https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault?debug=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer *my_token*
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "target": {
  "url": "https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/thing"
 },
 "type": "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
}

Response


401 Unauthorized

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  93
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Fri, 01 Mar 2013 18:56:34 GMT
expires:  Fri, 01 Mar 2013 18:56:34 GMT
server:  GSE
www-authenticate:  AuthSub realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest" allowed-scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login,https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthLogin"

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "message": "Unauthorized"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized"
 }
}
```

Tried to revoke google api explorer permissions and authenticated again. Nothing changed. Am I doing something wrong or g+ apis are not yet ready for production use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the APIs explorer currently will not work with writing app activity to Google because it isn't passing the requestvisibleactions field to the OAUTH2 flow. You can still do things manually as I'll describe below.

There are two things you need to do:

First, ensure that you are rendering the sign-in button with requestvisibleactions set for the app activity types you are inserting.  The following example shows how you would render sign-in with the add activity:

```
<div id="gConnect">
  <button class="g-signin"
      data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
      data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
      data-clientId="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
      data-callback="onSignInCallback"
      data-theme="dark"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
  </button>
</div>
```

Next, you will need to construct and write the app activity. The following example shows this using JavaScript:

```
  var payload = {
    "target": {
      "id" : "replacewithuniqueidforaddtarget",
      "image" : "http:\/\/www.google.com\/s2\/static\/images\/GoogleyEyes.png",
      "type" : "http:\/\/schema.org\/CreativeWork",
      "description" : "The description for the activity",
      "name":"An example of AddActivity"
    },
    "type":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/AddActivity",
    "startDate": "2012-10-31T23:59:59.999Z"
  };
  var args = {
    'path': '/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault',
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': JSON.stringify(payload),
    'callback': function(response) {
       console.log(response);
     }
  };

  gapi.client.request(args);
```

You can see a live demo here:

http://wheresgus.com/appactivitiesdemo

You can learn about all of the activity types from the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types

**Update**

Note the live demo has been updated with the following code and you should not be directly calling gapi.client.request:

```
writeListenActivity: function(url){
  var payload = {
    "type": "http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",
  }

  if (url != undefined){
    payload.target = { 'url' : url };
  }else{
    payload.target = {
      "type": "http:\/\/schema.org\/MusicRecording",
      "id": "uniqueidformusictarget",
      "description": "A song about missing one's family members fighting in the American Civil War",
      "image": "https:\/\/developers.google.com\/+\/plugins\/snippet\/examples\/song.png",
      "name": "When Johnny Comes Marching Home"
    };
  }
  this.writeAppActivity(payload);
},
writeAddActivity: function(url){
  var payload = {
    "type":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/AddActivity",
    "startDate": "2012-10-31T23:59:59.999Z"
  };
  if (url != undefined){
    payload.target = {
      'url' : 'https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing'
    };
  }else{
    payload.target = {
      "id" : "replacewithuniqueidforaddtarget",
      "image" : "http:\/\/www.google.com\/s2\/static\/images\/GoogleyEyes.png",
      "type" : "http:\/\/schema.org\/CreativeWork",
      "description" : "The description for the activity",
      "name":"An example of AddActivity"
    };
  }
  this.writeAppActivity(payload);
},
writeAppActivity: function(payload){

  gapi.client.plus.moments.insert(
      {  'userId' : 'me',
         'collection' : 'vault',
         'resource' : payload
      }).execute(function(result){
          console.log(result);
      });
}
```

Of particular note is the gapi.client.plus.moments.insert code that replaces the gapi.client.request call.

Comment: Great, looks like `requestvisibleactions` is the root of problem. And [this post](https://plus.google.com/118276561380249048216/posts/2kMX9Dzaf8V) lead to proper [diff](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/diff?spec=svn533&r=533&format=side&path=/trunk/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php) for server-side oauth authentication. 

Thanks for info!

Comment: @class What do you mean by "replacewithuniqueidforaddtarget" do you just type a random ID here or something?

Comment: For the target id, its just a random string as you suggested.

Comment: @class Are you sending the payload as a JSON file or just as a string?

Comment: The payload is a JSON string passed to the API endpoint. Note that in the code I initially shared on the answer (as opposed to the code on wheresgus that was updated) I was doing something bad, directly making a call to gapi.client.request when I should have been using the API client. Updated answer