# Google Moments in google's own php library, are not working

Tags: php, google-plus

I have struggled with google's php library, the latest version of which is available on their own website. While the simple google plus example they provide works fine (it's a basic login with `GET` features), there is no way to add a moment activity via app in php - at least not for me.
Their own example isn't working (the example can be retrievd in the library: examples/moments/simple.php)

Someone provides an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164949/google-unable-to-insert-moment#comment21361856_15167103) but the button demo they provide isn't working either if I press (authorization is fine, posting produces no action.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to change their own php file so to make it work? I tired removing all the code and resetting it to the basic action: at least I am not getting oauth or php errors, but the file produces no action.
I understand that posting moments in php is not currently supported, but I have a web app and android implementation wouldn't work for me I think.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the library? The version and quickstart linked from here: http://developers.google.com/+/downloads should be the latest.

Are you seeing any errors from the library? If so, what is the error code?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. THe quickstart and all the updated library I had tested already. Moments weren't working (the only thing that wasn't working). Someone kindly answered this question to solve the mystery though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you need to get the library from the trunk, you can find instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout).
[This gist](https://gist.github.com/silvolu/5054214) documents how to request permission and write activities.

The old moments api has been deprecated and those samples are for the old API, I'll remove them from the codebase as soon as possible. Thanks for raising this question!

Comment: thanks so much! I have banged my head for hours on moments. This explains a lot