# Google+ insert moment using google-api-dotnet-client

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to write an activity in Google+ using the dotnet-client. The issue is that I can't seem to get the configuration of my client app correctly. According to the [Google+ Sign-In configuration](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164949/google-unable-to-insert-moment#comment21361856_15167103) we need to add the requestvisibleactions parameter. I did that but it did not work. I am using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` and I even added the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write` but the insert still did not work.

This is what my request url looks like:

`https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600&continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope%3Dhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login%2Bhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write%26response_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp://localhost/%26state%3D%26requestvisibleactions%3Dhttp://schemas.google.com/AddActivity%26client_id%3D000.apps.googleusercontent.com%26request_visible_actions%3Dhttp://schemas.google.com/AddActivity%26hl%3Den%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D-1fbe06f1c6120f4d&ltmpl=popup&shdf=Cm4LEhF0aGlyZFBhcnR5TG9nb1VybBoADAsSFXRoaXJkUGFydHlEaXNwbGF5TmFtZRoHQ2hpa3V0bwwLEgZkb21haW4aB0NoaWt1dG8MCxIVdGhpcmRQYXJ0eURpc3BsYXlUeXBlGgdERUZBVUxUDBIDbHNvIhTeWybcoJ9pXSeN2t-k8A4SUbfhsygBMhQivAmfNSs_LkjXXZ7bPxilXgjMsQ&scc=1`

As you can see from there that there is a `request_visible_actions` and I even added one that has no underscore in case I got the parameter wrong (`requestvisibleactions`).

Let me say that my app is being authenticated successfully by the API. I can get the user's profile after being authenticated and it is on the "insert moment" part that my app fails. My insert code:

```
        var body = new Moment();
        var target = new ItemScope();
        target.Id = referenceId;
        target.Image = image;
        target.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";
        target.Description = description;
        target.Name = caption;

        body.Target = target;
        body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

        var insert =
            new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(
                // this is a valid service instance as I am using this to query the user's profile
                _plusService,
                body,
                id,
                MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);

        Moment result = null;
        try
        {
            result = insert.Fetch();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // User was not yet authenticated and is being forwarded to the authorization page.
            throw;
        }
        catch (Google.GoogleApiRequestException requestEx)
        {                
            // here I get a 401 Unauthorized error

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }            `
```

Comment: Are you using the Google+ Sign-In button on your page? If so can you paste that markup into your post? OR are you using native OAuth to trigger the URL that you show? I believe from the way the URL is formed that you are not using the button to trigger the auth, is there a reason?

Comment: I am using the dotnet client. The URL that I show was built by the API. I know that the dotnet client uses the DotNetOpenAuth (DNOA) so I am thinking it's the DNOA that builds the URL. Authentication is done via the `Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator`.

Comment: Oh and sorry I missed answering one of your question. I using my own link/button where I call a method that kicks off the authentication. My authentication code is based on the samples. I can post it as well if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah it's that simple! Maybe not? I am answering my own question and consequently accept it as the answer (after a few days of course) so others having the same issue may be guided. But I will definitely up-vote Gus' answer for it led me to the fix for my code.

So according to @class answer written above and as [explained on his blog](http://gusclass.com/blog/2013/02/27/common-issues-for-the-new-google-platform-release/) the key to successfully creating a moment is adding the `request_visible_actions` parameter. I did that but my request still failed and it is because I was missing an important thing. You need to add one more parameter and that is the **`access_type`** and it should be set to **`offline`**. The OAuth request, at a minimum, should look like: *https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/**&request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity&access_type=offline***.

For the complete and correct client code you can [get Gus' example here](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus_csharp_ssflow) or [download the entire dotnet client library including the source and sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads) and add what I added below. The most important thing that you should remember is modifying your `AuthorizationServerDescription` for the Google API. Here's my version of the authenticator:

```
public static OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient> CreateAuthenticator(
        string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId))
        throw new ArgumentException("clientId cannot be empty");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
        throw new ArgumentException("clientSecret cannot be empty");

    var description = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;

    var uri = description.AuthorizationEndpoint.AbsoluteUri;
    // This is the one that has been documented on Gus' blog site 
    // and over at Google's (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/)
    // This is not in the dotnetclient sample by the way 
    // and you need to understand how OAuth and DNOA works.
    // I had this already, see my original post, 
    // I thought it will make my day.
    if (uri.IndexOf("request_visible_actions") < 1)
    {
        var param = (uri.IndexOf('?') > 0) ? "&" : "?";
        description.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(
            uri + param +
            "request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
    }

    // This is what I have been missing! 
    // They forgot to tell us about this or did I just miss this somewhere?
    uri = description.AuthorizationEndpoint.AbsoluteUri;
    if (uri.IndexOf("offline") < 1)
    {
        var param = (uri.IndexOf('?') > 0) ? "&" : "?";
        description.AuthorizationEndpoint = 
                new Uri(uri + param + "access_type=offline");
    }

    // Register the authenticator.
    var provider = new WebServerClient(description)
    {
        ClientIdentifier = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret,                  
    };            
    var authenticator =
        new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(provider, GetAuthorization)
                 { NoCaching = true };
    return authenticator;
}
```

Without the **`access_type=offline`** my code never worked and it will never work. Now I wonder why? It would be good to have some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

For the OAuth flow, there are two issues with your request:

- request_visible_actions is what is passed to the OAuth v2 server (don't pass requestvisibleactions)
- plus.moments.write is a deprecated scope, you only need to pass in plus.login

Make sure your project references the latest version of the Google+ .NET client library from here:

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/stable/plus/v1/csharp

I have created a project on GitHub showing a full server-side flow here:

https://github.com/gguuss/gplus_csharp_ssflow

As Brettj said, you should be using the Google+ Sign-in Button as demonstrated in the latest Google+ samples from here:

https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp

First, *ensure* you are requesting all of the activity types you're writing.  You will know this is working because the authorization dialog will show "Make your app activity available via Google, visible to you and: [...]" below the text that starts with "This app would like to". I know you checked this but I'm 90% sure this is why you are getting the 401 error code. The following markup shows how to render the Google+ Sign-In button requesting access to Add activities.

```
<div id="gConnect">
<button class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-clientId="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-callback="onSignInCallback"
    data-theme="dark"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
</button>
```

Assuming you have a PlusService object with the correct activity type set in data-requestvisibleactions, the following code, which you should be able to copy/paste to see it work, concisely demonstrates writing moments using the .NET client and has been tested to work:

```
Moment body = new Moment();
ItemScope target = new ItemScope();

target.Id = "replacewithuniqueforaddtarget";
target.Image = "http://www.google.com/s2/static/images/GoogleyEyes.png";
target.Type = "";
target.Description = "The description for the activity";
target.Name = "An example of add activity";

body.Target = target;
body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert =
    new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(
        _plusService,
        body,
        "me",
        MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
Moment wrote = insert.Fetch();
```

Note, I'm including Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data for convenience.

Comment: HI @class I passed in `requestvisibleactions` in hope that it will work, I thought maybe the arg name changed. I actually tried both: (1) with `requestvisibleactions` and (2) with `request_visible_actions` and nothing worked. Also, the snippet you gave me is the same as what I have except for: (1) target.Type where I tried with `AddActivity` and without and both did not work. (2) "me", my "id" is equals to "me". We have the same code but it does not work for me. It leads me to think something is missing on the dotnet client where it doesn't include the requestvisibleactions parameter properly?

Comment: Also, allow me to say it again, my code works for logging in and getting the user's profile. So I'm sure my authentication is just missing a configuration so I can create an activity. By the way, my first attempt was without the `plus.moments.write` scope, it did not work and that leads me to adding it in - I thought maybe it will work. No joy.

Comment: @vonv. I added my project to GitHub, hopefully that can help you debug. Make sure you're only passing request_visible_actions. You will know your authorization request is correct when you see the UI text change indicating the app activities are being requested. Also, to double-check here, you are doing a server-side flow? A final thing that could be causing the issue is that you have an older library, added a link to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @class I will check out the github sample. Yes I'm doing a server-side flow and yes I'm using the current lib `1.2.4737.25316`.

I got interested on the Sign-In button I actually sort of prefer it as it is similar to the FB js SDK I am using. I'm doing ajax most of the time and it make sense that the authentication is kicked off from the client side. The server-side will still have validation of course. I think I need to create a new thread about this. I'll tag you on that new question. Thanks again, will let you know about the result.