# Google Plus API Moment.Insert

Tags: google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying for moment.insert using google-api-dotnet-client and also included the request_visible_actions and access_type in oauth request but I am always getting exception:

**The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Google.Apis.Discovery.BaseService.GetResource(IResource root, String fullResourceName) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Discovery\Service.cs:line 279
   at Google.Apis.Discovery.BaseService.CreateRequest(String resource, String methodName) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Discovery\Service.cs:line 186
   at Plus.v1.PlusService.CreateRequest(String resource, String method)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.BuildRequest() in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ServiceRequest.cs:line 134
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.GetAsyncResponse(Action`1 responseHandler) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ServiceRequest.cs:line 169
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.GetResponse() in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ServiceRequest.cs:line 185
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.Fetch() in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ServiceRequest.cs:line 211
   at VocalbeeWebApp.Controllers.HomeController.CheckGooglePlusAuthorization() in d:\Projects\VocalBee\VocalBeeSocialServer-T\VocalbeeWebApp\VocalbeeWebApp\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 217
```

Below is the code snippet for moment.insert:

```
            Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data.Moment body = new Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data.Moment();
            Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data.ItemScope target = new Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data.ItemScope();

            target.Id = "target-id";
            target.Image = "http://www.vocalbee.com/Images/WebLogoNewSmall.png";
            target.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";
            target.Description = "The description for the activity";
            target.Name = "An example of add activity";

            body.Target = target;
            body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";
            Google.Apis.Plus.v1.MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert =
                new Google.Apis.Plus.v1.MomentsResource.InsertRequest(
                    pw.plusService,
                    body,
                    me.Id,
                    Google.Apis.Plus.v1.MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
            Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data.Moment result = insert.Fetch();
```

Can anybody help me in figuring out the problem?

Comment: This can be considered a duplicate of [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263378/google-insert-moment-using-google-api-dotnet-client) given that the same solution is posted there and I've documented it in my own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be using an older version of the library.  The latest version is available from here:

- [Google+ Downloads](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/)
- [Google+ .NET client library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/plus/v1/csharp)

Make sure that you replace all of the older client library dependencies with the newer ones. You should at least replace existing versions of:

- Google.Apis.dll
- Google.Apis.Plus.v1.dll

An example of refreshing the tokens offline is in the [Google+ Quickstart Demo (C#/.NET)](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp/blob/master/gplus-quickstart-csharp/signin.ashx.cs)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I got it working with your answer. The version of library I downloaded was older.

Do you have any idea how we can refresh the access_token without user interaction?

Comment: Example added to answer.