# Error in simple insertion (moment) in my google+ page (. Net)

Tags: c#, vb.net, api, google-plus

Good Night,

I tried adding the parameters as the comments, however to no avail.
I got the following code, however now the error is now ...

```
ProtocolException as caught
Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
```

Can someone help me because I'm almost thinking it is not possible.

```
Public Shared Function PostPlus2(sMsg As String) As Boolean
        Try

            Dim sPath_Absolut As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/funcoes/")

            Dim ServiceAccountId As String = "****************************.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            Dim ServiceAccountUser As String = "***************************@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
            Dim Certificado As String = sPath_Absolut + "Certificado\privatekey.p12"

            Dim oCertificate As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(Certificado, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable) 'Or X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet

            'Dim GooAuthServer As DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description
            'GooAuthServer.AuthorizationEndpoint = New Uri(GooAuthServer.AuthorizationEndpoint.AbsoluteUri + "?" + "request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" + "&" + "access_type=offline")
            'Dim oClient As New AssertionFlowClient(GooAuthServer, oCertificate) With

            Dim oClient As New AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, oCertificate) With
            {
            .ServiceAccountId = ServiceAccountUser,
            .ServiceAccountUser = "************@gmail.com",
            .Scope = Plus.v1.PlusService.Scopes.PlusMe.GetStringValue()
                                }


            Dim oAuth As New OAuth2Authenticator(Of AssertionFlowClient)(oClient, AddressOf AssertionFlowClient.GetState)
            Dim oInitializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer() With
            {
            .Authenticator = oAuth
            }

            Dim oPlusServ As New Plus.v1.PlusService(oInitializer)

            Dim body As New Plus.v1.Data.Moment()
            Dim target As New Plus.v1.Data.ItemScope()
            target.Id = "4"
            target.Image = "http://www.google.com/s2/static/images/GoogleyEyes.png"
            target.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            target.Description = "teste description"
            target.Name = "teste name"
            target.Url = "https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/thing"

            body.Target = target
            body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"

            Dim insert As New Plus.v1.MomentsResource.InsertRequest(
                    oPlusServ,
                    body,
                    "me",
                    Plus.v1.MomentsResource.Collection.Vault)

            insert.Fetch()
            'Dim wrote As Plus.v1.Data.Moment = insert.Fetch()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: +1 for not forgetting to hide the real login data

Answer (score 2):

To be able to write an AppActivity, you need to set the request-visible-actions parameter when configuring your Google+ Sign-In button. This parameter indicates which AppActivityTypes you intend to write. You can learn more at https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/?hl=en or by watching this Google+ Developers Live episode: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQC_EanIaUw#t=6m46s.

Comment: Good Morning, thank you for your attention.

I would like to post on my own page on google+, I only, so I'm using "google account" because I will not ask for the key to the User.

I the following link that gave me however has no example in VB.net or C # instead are using OAuth directly, you must specify the request_visible_actions. How do I?

Comment: Have you tried retrieving an access token by sending an HTTP request, and then posting another HTTP request?

You could then write code around these HTTP requests to make it easier to use. I did the same thing in Java, wrote a GoogleProfile class which underneath sends HTTP requests using an OAuth2 token

Comment: The stack overflow question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263378/google-insert-moment-using-google-api-dotnet-client/15285699#15285699 - shows how to set request_visible_actions using the traditional OAuth2 flow and includes C# code for doing this using .NET.  You might want to try doing this using the C# Quickstart on Github here as well - https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp

Comment: I went to the link, added the Paramenters "request_visible_actions" and "access_type", but still the error persists.