# Google plus insert moment stopped working using google-api-dotnet-client

Tags: .net, google-api, google-plus, dotnetopenauth, google-api-dotnet-client

**The question is:** Is there a new way in calling the API so an activity can be inserted into a user's profile?

I posted [a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263378/google-insert-moment-using-google-api-dotnet-client) about a month ago. It was working fine until early this week when it suddenly stopped working and complained about this error:

> **[error message]**
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response
>
> **[inner exception]**
>
> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> **[stack trace]**
>
> at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
>
> at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request)
>
> at  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.GetDirectResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   webRequest)
>
> at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage
>   request)
>
> at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage
>   requestMessage)
>
> at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.UpdateAuthorizationWithResponse(IAuthorizationState
>   authorizationState, EndUserAuthorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse
>   authorizationSuccess)
>
> at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(HttpRequestInfo
>   request)
>
> at GPlusWrapper.PlusWrapper.GetAuthorization(WebServerClient client) in
>   \gplus_csharp_ssflow\PlusWrapper.cs:line
>   122
>
> at Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator`1.LoadAccessToken()
>
> at Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator`1.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(HttpWebRequest
>   request)
>
>   at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.CreateWebRequest(Action`1
>   onRequestReady)    at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.Request.ExecuteRequestAsync(Action`1
>   responseHandler)    at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.GetAsyncResponse(Action`1
>   responseHandler)    at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.GetResponse()    at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.Fetch()

At first glance one that is experienced in Google API and DNOA would say it's a DNOA issue. I've been searching for three days and the issues that I found having the same error message does not fit the issue - or the solution proposed does not fit the issue I have.

So the next thing to do is to upgrade, yes, it make sense as the Google team may have changed something on how the API works. So I upgraded from `v1.2.4737.25316` to `v1.3.0.15233`, which is **the latest stable version** [in the repo](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/stable/plus/v1/csharp).

To make sure that it is not my code or something in my code that causes the issue, I've revisited [Gus' sample code given here](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus_csharp_ssflow). That sample code used to work in `v1.2` but also stopped working in both `v1.2` and `v1.3`.

Now since there is a new version of the library, it only make sense to re-visit [the docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) and see if something changed in the configuration or how to call the API. There seems to be nothing different in the way the API should be called.

So I did what I did the last time in debugging the application. I tried both

- request_visible_actions; and
- requestvisibleactions

and I still had the `access_type` parameter and nothing worked.

**Again, my question is:** Is there a new way in calling the API so an activity can be inserted into a user's profile?

*Please take note that I am using the server-side flow*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the [quickstart working](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp), you can make API calls for writing app activities. To test this, find the following line of code in the quickstart:

```
ps = new PlusService(authenticator);
```

At this point, if you've successfully authorized, you can create a moment object and write it to Google:

```
Moment body = new Moment();
body.Target = new ItemScope();
body.Target.Url = “https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/widget”;
body.Type = “http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity”;
ps.Moments.Insert(body, “me”, MomentsResource.Collection.Vault).Fetch();
```

I just tested the code, it still works, which means that the library is still able to make API calls. On second glance, I remembered [you had asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263378/google-insert-moment-using-google-api-dotnet-client), which makes me wonder if it's something specific to the SS flow. After a little debugging, I'm encountering the same issue as you running SS, however, the client is receiving the authorization code - a good sign. The client library is failing even though I'm removing the hack to pump in request_visible_actions - a bad sign.

Using request_visible_actions is still correct and underneath the hood, the client library is using the OAuth V2 flow, which should not have changed.

### Final update:

I [changed my example server-side demo](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus_csharp_ssflow) to manually exchange the authorization code for the access token / refresh token. Please grab it again from GitHub to see if that helps but this is a quick and dirty temporary fix. I'll look into why the client library is breaking on the code exchange part.

P.S. I'm aware of the v1.3 changes, hopefully I'll make the time to perform the code updates soon! I thought nobody would notice...

Comment: Hi Gus', I was about to reply that I was using another sample project you gave, that we both linked to in this Q&A. Good thing I noticed you updated your answer. I will get that updated sample code and will let you know of the result. But let me thank you now (a lot!) for taking time to look into the issue and creating a solution  (even if it's temporary) :)

Comment: I still got an error with the updated code: `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` The type of exception though is now a `ProtocolError`. There is nothing else to describe the error, no innerexception. The error is on line 75 of ManualCodeExchanger ->`WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()`

Comment: Ah nvm, my bad. I changed the port that the project is using so I can run it on my machine. I did not notice that you are using a RedirectUri as part of the temporary fix. I just have to changed that. All works now. Thanks! @class is there a place where I can subscribe to if you have updates to the library? Like if you have an update to this issue?

Comment: The official updates for Google+ will be on their GitHub page: https://github.com/googleplus