# Google Plus API Authorization: request_visible_actions

Tags: objective-c, api, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I'm using the [GTL framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary) to integrate Google Plus in my cocoa application.

When I try to insert a new moment it fails with error 401 (unauthorized). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156417/google-plus-cant-post-a-moment) post the TO solved this problem by including the `request_visible_actions` parameter while redirecting the user to the authorization page. But how to do that?

I got an instance of a `GTMOAuth2WindowController` that automatically creates the URL. So how can I add the `request_visible_actions` parameter? When that's not possible, how to create the whole URL?

Comment: May you show me how you set-up the Google Plus Moment POST request? Mine isn't working :( (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061521/cannot-insert-moment-google-plus-api)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem! I had to create the `GTMOAuth2WindowController` like this:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2SignIn standardGoogleAuthenticationForScope:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin clientID:kClientID clientSecret:kClientSecret];
NSString *authURLString = [[[GTMOAuth2SignIn googleAuthorizationURL] absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:@"?request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"];

NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[GTMOAuth2WindowController class]];
GTMOAuth2WindowController *windowController = [GTMOAuth2WindowController controllerWithAuthentication:auth
                                                                                                       authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authURLString]
                                                                                                          keychainItemName:nil
                                                                                                           resourceBundle:frameworkBundle];
```

Comment: SO you are connecting "?request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" to "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/"???